# python 3.4.3 unable to write to a file in a desktop folder

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a simple code to write a file in a specific folder. System creates the file in the folder but couldn't write on it. It is on windows and I checked the IDE write access (Pycharm) they seems fine. File is empty. 
Following with code is to read whether I could write or ensure the previous one is finished. It is not writing the short string to the file.  I have tried it on command line but it didn't work there also.

```
with open ('C:/Users/***/Desktop/***/output.log',mode ='w', encoding ='utf-8') as a_file:
    a_file.write ="test"

with open ('C:/Users/***/Desktop/***/output.log', encoding ='utf-8') as a_file:
    print(a_file.read())
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`write`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.TextIOBase.write) is a method (function), you need to call, instead of assigning to it.

```
with open ('C:/Users/***/Desktop/***/output.log', mode='w', encoding='utf-8') as a_file:
    a_file.write("test")  # <---
```